# iOS - How to avoid type casting with protocols Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to avoid type casting when protocols are used. For example:

```
protocol SomeService: AnyObject {
    func process(token: Token)
}

protocol Token {
   var token: String { get set }
}

class TestService: SomeService {
    func process(token: Token) {
       guard let token = token as? TestToken else {
          return
       }

       // Do something with TestToken
    }
}

class TestToken: Token {
   var token: String = "tokenValue"
   var key: String = "keyValue"
}
```

If there are more classes that are to conform to `SomeService` protocol with their own `Token` conformed objects and additional values (like key), I don't want to type cast for each class.

Comment: The goal is to express all the relevant parts of a token in the interface of the `Token` protocol. If that's done, `TestService.process(token:)` doesn't have to cast anything, because it has no reason to care what the concrete type of `token` is. All it needs to know is that it can use the properties/functions/subscripts/initializers that the `Token` protocol requires of its conforming types, and that it can use those to do its work.

Comment: can I say it's better to approach this problem with associatedType for my use case?

Comment: I have no idea, because I don't know what your problem is, nor your use case.

Comment: Make your method generic `func process<T:Token>(token: T) {`